# Joining three tables with junction table

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have three tables.
When an activity is created, the column **user_id** in **table activity** gets the **user id** of the creator (**FK to user.id**).
Then I make an insert into the junction **table attending**, like for example **user_id 1** is attending **activity_id 4**.
If a user is joining an activity, I just make the insert into the junction **table attending** like **user_id 5 activity_id 6**.
What I want is to select **all activities** where the user is **not attending** or has **created**.

But with this select I'm still getting activities where the user is attending even though I have the **WHERE CLAUSE** with the specific **!= user id**.

To clarify with an example; let's say **user id 3** created **activity id 3**.
Then **user id 1** attends **activity id 3**.
That means when I run the select I don't want **activity id 3** to be in the result if I use the **WHERE CLAUSE with ID 1**, but I am still getting it.

```
Cursor result =  db.rawQuery( "select activity.id, activity.activity, activity.time, activity.attenders, activity.place, activity.payment, user.name, user.birthdate, user.rating " +
                "FROM activity " +
                "INNER JOIN user ON user.id = activity.user_id " +
                "INNER JOIN attending ON attending.activity_id = activity.id " +
                "WHERE attending.user_id != "+id+"", null );
```

```
create table user (id integer primary key, name text, password text, birthdate text, phone text, email text, position text, presentation text, rating real, created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

create table attending (user_id integer, activity_id integer, created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(id), FOREIGN KEY (activity_id) REFERENCES activity(id))

create table activity (id integer primary key, activity text, attenders integer, time text, place text, payment text, description text, user_id integer, created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(id))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are encountering is that the JOINS will introduce more data than you expect (see below for a more comprehensive explanation).

I believe that the following query will do as you wish :-

```
WITH 
  base_user AS (SELECT 1 /* <<<<<<<<<< VALUE THAT SHOULD BE CHANGED >>>>>>>>>*/),
    exclude_creator_activities AS (SELECT * FROM activity WHERE activity.user_id != (SELECT * FROM base_user))
SELECT DISTINCT exclude_creator_activities.id, exclude_creator_activities.activity, exclude_creator_activities.time, exclude_creator_activities.attenders, exclude_creator_activities.place, exclude_creator_activities.payment, user.name, user.birthdate, user.rating 
    FROM exclude_creator_activities
        JOIN user ON user.id = exclude_creator_activities.user_id
    JOIN attending ON attending.activity_id = exclude_creator_activities.id
  WHERE attending.activity_id NOT IN(SELECT activity_id FROM attending WHERE user_id = (SELECT * FROM base_user))
;
```

That is two CTE's (Common Table Expressions (temporary tables)) are used namely :-

- **base_user** which is used so that the user id need only be specified once.
- **exclude_creator_activities** which creates a subset of the activity table with only activities that are not created by the user (1st use of the **base_user** CTE).

Then instead of using the activity table the subset CTE **exclude_creator_activities** is used to only look at activities not created by the user. Roughly speaking the query is very much as as your original query (no need for INNER as it's the same as JOIN), with the exception of 
 the use of DISTINCT and the WHERE clause and of course that it is based upon the CTE **exclude_creator_activities**.

- **More Comprehensive explanation**
- The WHERE clause excludes any rows whose activity is an activity attended by the user (2nd use of the **base_user** CTE) rather than just excluding rows that have the user (this, I believe, being the issue that was confusing you, that is if another user attended the activity then that activity would be included).

All you have to do is convert the above into the string used in the raw query.

- **Note** ideally you should use the **?** argument placement character and the 2nd parameter for raw query, instead of **null** for the id rather than concatenating it to the string *(to stop the SQL injection police squad from injecting their comments)*.

## Testing

Consider the following which could be dropped into your favourite SQLite management tool such as Navicat DB Browser for SQLite etc :-

```
/* Just in case */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS attending;
DROP TABLE If EXISTS activity;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user;

/* Create the tables */
create table IF NOT EXISTS user (id integer primary key, name text, password text, birthdate text, phone text, email text, position text, presentation text, rating real, created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
create table IF NOT EXISTS activity (id integer primary key, activity text, attenders integer, time text, place text, payment text, description text, user_id integer, created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(id));
create table IF NOT EXISTS attending (user_id integer, activity_id integer, created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(id), FOREIGN KEY (activity_id) REFERENCES activity(id));

/* Add some testing data */
INSERT INTO USER (name) VALUES('FRED'),('MARY'),('SUE'),('JOHN');
INSERT INTO activity (activity,user_id) VALUES('A1',1),('A2',1),('A3',3),('A4',1),('A5',2);
INSERT INTO attending (user_id,activity_id) VALUES
    (2,1),(3,1), /* Add attendees MARY and SUE to A1 which is created by FRED */
    (3,2),(4,2), /* Add attendees SUE and JOHN to A2 which is created by FRED */    
    (1,3),       /* Add attendees FRED to A3 which is created by SUE */
    (2,4),(4,4), /* Add attendees MARY and JOHN to A4 which is created by FRED */
    (3,5),(4,5)  /* add attendees SUE and JOHN to A5 which is created by MARY */
;

/* Test the queries for each user */
/* For FRED who will not show A1 or A2 or A4 as FRED is the creator, will not show A3 as FRED is attendee */
WITH 
  base_user AS (SELECT 1),
    exclude_creator_activities AS (SELECT * FROM activity WHERE activity.user_id != (SELECT * FROM base_user))
SELECT DISTINCT exclude_creator_activities.id, exclude_creator_activities.activity, exclude_creator_activities.time, exclude_creator_activities.attenders, exclude_creator_activities.place, exclude_creator_activities.payment, user.name, user.birthdate, user.rating 
    FROM exclude_creator_activities
        JOIN user ON user.id = exclude_creator_activities.user_id
    JOIN attending ON attending.activity_id = exclude_creator_activities.id
  WHERE attending.activity_id NOT IN(SELECT activity_id FROM attending WHERE user_id = (SELECT * FROM base_user))
;

/* For MARY who will not show A5 as MARY is the creator, will not show A1, A4 as MARY is attendee */
WITH 
  base_user AS (SELECT 2),
    exclude_creator_activities AS (SELECT * FROM activity WHERE activity.user_id != (SELECT * FROM base_user))
SELECT DISTINCT exclude_creator_activities.id, exclude_creator_activities.activity, exclude_creator_activities.time, exclude_creator_activities.attenders, exclude_creator_activities.place, exclude_creator_activities.payment, user.name, user.birthdate, user.rating 
    FROM exclude_creator_activities
        JOIN user ON user.id = exclude_creator_activities.user_id
    JOIN attending ON attending.activity_id = exclude_creator_activities.id
  WHERE attending.activity_id NOT IN(SELECT activity_id FROM attending WHERE user_id = (SELECT * FROM base_user))
;

/* For SUE who will not show A3 as SUE is the creator, will not show A1, A2, A5 as SUE is attendee */
WITH 
  base_user AS (SELECT 3),
    exclude_creator_activities AS (SELECT * FROM activity WHERE activity.user_id != (SELECT * FROM base_user))
SELECT DISTINCT exclude_creator_activities.id, exclude_creator_activities.activity, exclude_creator_activities.time, exclude_creator_activities.attenders, exclude_creator_activities.place, exclude_creator_activities.payment, user.name, user.birthdate, user.rating 
    FROM exclude_creator_activities
        JOIN user ON user.id = exclude_creator_activities.user_id
    JOIN attending ON attending.activity_id = exclude_creator_activities.id
  WHERE attending.activity_id NOT IN(SELECT activity_id FROM attending WHERE user_id = (SELECT * FROM base_user))
;

/* For JOHN will not show A2, A3, A4 as JOHN is attendee */
WITH 
  base_user AS (SELECT 4),
    exclude_creator_activities AS (SELECT * FROM activity WHERE activity.user_id != (SELECT * FROM base_user))
SELECT DISTINCT exclude_creator_activities.id, exclude_creator_activities.activity, exclude_creator_activities.time, exclude_creator_activities.attenders, exclude_creator_activities.place, exclude_creator_activities.payment, user.name, user.birthdate, user.rating 
    FROM exclude_creator_activities
        JOIN user ON user.id = exclude_creator_activities.user_id
    JOIN attending ON attending.activity_id = exclude_creator_activities.id
  WHERE attending.activity_id NOT IN(SELECT activity_id FROM attending WHERE user_id = (SELECT * FROM base_user))
;

/* Clean up everything */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS attending;
DROP TABLE If EXISTS activity;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user;
```

- **Note** only minimal/required data is been added, so a lot of the data will be null in the results (for convenience).

## Results :-

- **Note** refer to the comments in the code for what should be excluded and why.

### 1 User **FRED** :-

[image]

### 2 User **MARY**

[image]

### 3 User **SUE**

[image]

### 4 User **JOHN**

[image]

Comment: I just tested it and it works perfectly, thanks a lot for this! I have tried to solve this for 3 whole days in row... Thank you again mr.

Comment: I have another problem, i had to change database from sql to Mysql... And typically it does not support CTE's, so i tried your solution with temporary tables but again Mysql is complaining when i create two temporary tables. If you would be so kind to help me write this query in mysql i would be very grateful mr!

Comment: @Gotcha I believe that CTE's are suppored in MySQL see [Common Table Expression Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-syntax).

Comment: Only mysql version 8.0 supports CTE and the server im using has an older version and im bound to their service so i have no options sadly... But thanks anyways i'll manage it somehow :)